# How to check the execution environment being used in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to import the package `java.util.concurrent` in my Java project, but it is not available. This project is developed in Eclipse, and my Eclipse is using JRE6. `java.util.concurrent` package is available since Java 1.5, and how come JRE6 does not contain Java 1.5?

My only guess is that Eclipse is currently using an execution environment that is older than Java 1.5, but how can I verify that?

Or, is there any other way to import a package that is not shown in the drop down selection box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project

```
Properties -> Java Built Path -> Libraries ->Check the JRE/JDK is at least 1.5

Properties ->Java Compiler -> check if the Compiler is at least 1.5
```

Comment: Yes, in the Java build pathm JRE is set to jre6, and in java compiler, the complience level is 5.0. can't imagine why it doesnt work fo rme.

Comment: try to add some non functional generic code into one of your classes like add a generic List object to see if it complains about a compile error

Comment: Do you meanimport java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.List; yes, they are working fine

Comment: i just checked for the availability of another packge introduce in 1.5 (java.lang.management), this is also not there. Seeme like my eclipse is running on a previous version :S

Comment: no, what I mean is, add this for eg ;  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  does it compile generic code or gives an error?

Answer (score 1):

Help->About->Installation Details->Configuration. 
You can also try setting the VM path dirrectly in ecipse.ini.

> -vm
>   {$path_to_jdk$}/jdk1.6.0_18/bin

Comment: thanks a lot, i found out that in the configuration details the VM path has been set to somewhere else. So I changes the eclipse.ini and also added the vm parameter to the target property of my shortcut. But stil I cannot see the util.concurrent package. i don't know what's really wrong.

Comment: Maybe see this link [Find the JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM) .Bsically just copy the jdk folder in your eclipse folder. Then in the eclipse.ini file you only need to add the relative path `"-vm
jdk/jdk1.6.0_18/bin"` . Note that a newline after -wm is mandatory.